# keyboard and touch pad not working hp pavilion g6 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, touchpad

So back two days ago I was trying to install KDE on my Ubuntu 16.04 and it didn't go well (might not be the cause) and when I restarted my the keyboard and touchpad just doesn't work.

I tried installing Windows 10 thinking it'd fix the problem, but it didn't help. I tried everything. I completely cleaned the motherboard and checked everything their and its all fine. And sometimes when I start the system the brightness keys work for some seconds.

Please help guys. Thanks in advance!

`Xinput` list result:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam-101                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and this file is empty

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: and yeah there's no hardware fault in the keyboard cuz when i wake it from suspend using any of the keys it works. and its not even working on BIOS!

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same problem on my girlfriends Pavilion G6, only the F keys work since the update. Keys dont work in the bios for me either. A usb keyboard plugged in is fine.

Have faffed about in keyboard config file and tried a few set ups but no joy

Comment: If keys don't work in BIOS it's not a Ubuntu issue.